# Как можно сделать чтобы на одном div менялись несколько фоток?

Tags: jquery, css

Как можно сделать чтобы на одном div менялись несколько фоток? Идея такая: таблица 10х4 и в каждой ячейке чтобы с периодом 3с менялись фотки, которых в запасе 20.

Мне там наложить их друг на друга и использовать z-index'ы или есть более легкий метод?

Просто мне нужно чтобы они по рандому менялись и каждая фотка была уникальна к данному времени

Answer (score 4):

Логичнее всего на javascript.

```
 - Создайте массив фоток
 - Сделайте интервал таймера скажем 3сек
 - Рандомно выбирайте ID ячейки(блока), рандомно выбирайте фотку из массива
 - Меняйте background или src (если используйте img)
 - Рандомно меняйте интервал скажем от 2х до 5 секунд
```

Сейчас накидаю пример, самому инетерсно.

Comment: жду. Меня интересует уникальность. Как этого добиться?

Comment: я не яваскрипт программер, но чтото бодобное:

http://jsfiddle.net/uKBJP/

Answer (score 0):

Можно через javascript сделать просто небольшой слайдер со слайдшоу в каждой ячейке и ставить им время ожидания 3 секунды ( ну или сколько надо )

Answer (score -2):

Это слишком сложная задача для современных компьютеров, думаю лет через 100 появится возможность как то реализовать подобное. Но не сейчас...